# How to set `evil-insert-state-cursor` to a function?

Tags: evil, cursor

In evil-mode, the cursor shape and colour for each state is controlled by the series of variables `evil-*-state-cursor`. The documentation for these variables states:

> May be a cursor type as per `cursor-type`, a color string as passed
>   to `set-cursor-color`, a zero-argument function for changing the
>   cursor, or a list of the above.

However, when I attempt to use such a nullary function to make the shape of `evil-insert-state-cursor` dependent on the value of `overwrite-mode`, it doesn't work:

```
(setq evil-insert-state-cursor
      (lambda()
        (cond (overwrite-mode '("chartreuse3" (hbar . 2)))
              (t              '("chartreuse3" (bar  . 2))))))
```

The result of this is that the insert cursor changes to a hollow box in the same colour as the normal state cursor (Darkgoldenrod2 on my system). If I use a named function instead, I get a solid box (ie. identical to the normal state cursor).

I've also attempted to use a function that actually *sets* the value of `evil-insert-state-cursor`, rather than simply returning it. The result was the same. In general, setting the variable to *any* function results in a solid cursor, while setting it to any symbol/quoted sexp or lambda results in a hollow cursor.

How can I set a state-cursor variable to a function effectively?

*(I've found the answer to this before posting, but since I've already written the question, I might as well post it with the answer in case anyone else is searching for it.)*

Answer (score 1):

So I've found the answer to this is `evil-states.el`. Here's an example of a cursor defined with a function:

```
(evil-define-state operator
  "Operator-Pending state."
  :tag " <O> "
  :cursor evil-half-cursor
  :enable (evil-operator-shortcut-map operator motion normal))
```

...and the function definition:

```
;; the half-height "Operator-Pending cursor" cannot be specified
;; as a static `cursor-type' value, since its height depends on
;; the current font size
(defun evil-half-cursor ()
  "Change cursor to a half-height box.
\(This is really just a thick horizontal bar.)"
  (let ((height (/ (window-pixel-height) (* (window-height) 2))))
    (setq cursor-type (cons 'hbar height))))
```

As you can see, the function must set the `cursor-type` variable with the appropriate value.

This example is a bit different from my use-case, since the cursor doesn't need to change after the state is entered. Reasonably enough, evil doesn't re-evaluate the function every keystroke, so for a use-case like mine, we also need to invoke `evil-refresh-cursor` to do as its name implies.

Additionally, this ignores cursor-colour, so the cursor will have whatever colour it had last (probably from normal-state). We can fix this by also calling `set-cursor-color` in our function.

#### Solution:

```
(defun my/evil-insert-overwrite-cursor ()
  (set-cursor-color "chartreuse3")
  (setq cursor-type (if overwrite-mode (cons 'hbar 2) (cons 'bar 2))))

(setq evil-insert-state-cursor #'my/evil-insert-overwrite-cursor)

(defun my/enter-overwrite-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively #'overwrite-mode)
  (evil-refresh-cursor))

(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "<insert>") 'my/enter-overwrite-mode)
```

**note:** There is an `overwrite-mode-hook`, so we could add `evil-refresh-cursor` to that, to be sure it will always be triggered. However, I only expect to enter overwrite-mode with <kbd>Insert</kbd> and I prefer to use wrapper functions unless hooks are necessary.